# bypass trigger on specific object in salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger, customsetting, after-trigger

I need to bypass trigger on account sometime.
I have created custom setting for that and added triggerObject__c field.

In my code

```
  bypassTrigger__c bypass = 
  bypassTrigger__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getprofileId());
    if(!(bypass.TriggerObject__c.contains('account'))) {
```

its throwing Null pointer exception when there is no value in custom setting triggerObject__c .Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add one null check.

```
bypassTrigger__c bypass = bypassTrigger__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getprofileId());
if(bypass != null && bypass.TriggerObject__c != null && !(bypass.TriggerObject__c.contains('account'))) {
```

Note: If there is no record in the custom setting, your trigger will run.

Comment: its still not working

Comment: @sandy updated the code please check